# Getting AJAX content into the DOM or registering an object with jQuery via an onClick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I have a code setup something like below, the image is part of a block of HTML and is being loaded with AJAX so I can't get a direct handle on it using it's class or id, so I'm passing the object into a function and then picking it up with jQuery from there.

I don't like this method, is there any way of registering the image (**or preferably the whole HTML block**) with the DOM so I can get a direct handle on it with jQuery and be able to do something like `$(".img").click(function(){});` or is there a more elegant way of doing what I'm trying to do below:

My HTML Page:

```
<img src="m.jpg" onClick="vote(this);" class="img">
```

My JS page:

```
function vote(object)
{
    //alert('voted');
    $(object).css('display','none');
}
```

**Edit: Thanks everyone who answered, +1 to all. I'm not sure who said it first, but it solved everything.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
$('img.img').live('click', function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the JQuery live function should sort this out for you - you could attach a click to all images of the specific class and it should reapply as the DOM is reloaded when the image is downloaded.

[JQuery live function](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.voteImg').live('click', function() {
      //alert('voted');
      $(this).hide();
   });
});
```